# How to remove unwanted period in biblatex reference list after using finentry?

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a publication that requires me to highlight specific references for special interest. In the references list, the citation needs to have a asterisk like this: "[3] * Author, etc".

Based on some other answers on the internet (sorry, did this weeks ago, can't find the posts anymore) I wrote the code below. The command `\bibnote` allows me to do:
`\bibnote{citationkey}{Note about this particular article.}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bibnote}[2]{\csdef{cbx@#1@bibnote}{#2}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}{%
    *%
}{}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}{%
    \\\textit{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}}%
}{}}
\makeatother
```

The code works, with one annoying caveat: each reference in the list now ends with a newline and period, followed by the next entry:

[1] Author, Title, ...
.[2] Author, Title, ...
.[3] * Author, Title, ...

I've tried digging into the code of biblatex, but I wasn't able to remove the period. `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\nopunct}` does nothing. Anyone with enough knowledge of biblatex to help me solve this problem?

Another problem is that in the text, the citations of interest need to have an asterisk like this: "[3*]". I now solve that when citing, using post-notes, but that's quite error-prone. Is there a way to automatically add a post-note to every citation based on the citation key?

Comment: I deleted my suggestion as it is not appropriate for your situation, especially if changing the keywords will apply globally in your database. Hope someone else can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion anyway, @LaccaseTVersicolor.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the asterisk to the `labelnumber` field format, you can get it in citations and the bibliography at the same time.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\bibnote}[2]{\csdef{cbx@#1@bibnote}{#2}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}
    {}
    {\\\textit{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}}}%
  \finentry
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  #1%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}
    {}
    {*}}

\bibnote{sigfridsson}{Note about this particular article.}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [2*] dolor [3] sit [1]]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this is not meet the requirements of the journal I'm submitting my paper to. The answer might help others with similar questions, though, so I would leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

In proper fashion I figured out what was wrong myself. I'll let the post up for others to see.

The renewal of the bibmacro `finentry` was missing the call `\finentry`. The command `\finentry` is separate from the bibmacro `finentry` and calls `\blx@initunit`, which starts the next entry (I think).

My current solution is:

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}{%
    \\\textit{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@bibnote}}%
  }{}%
  \finentry%
}
```

My second question wasn't solved yet.